# Running OpenLayers in .NET 4.5 breaks

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, openlayers

So, I'm writing an web mapping application using OpenLayers in WebForms in .NET 4.5.

It was working wonderfully until my browser upgraded to IE9. Now the JavaScript fails. After researching I found that the problem seems to be that IE9 changed how it handles certain kinds of JavaScript. So the solution, until the community can rewrite the JavaScript libraries, seems to be to have the browser run in compatibility mode. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get compatibility mode to work correctly.

Currently my application has one page and this is the header:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AgPlaceHolder._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
<title>Agrilogic Place Holder</title>
<script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="AgInit.js"></script>
<script src="AgLabels.js"></script>

<style>
    html, body
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```

It didn't work. So I found this alternative to add to the web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

This also didn't work.

I've tried some variations I've seen used around, but none of them seem to be working. Does anyone see what I might have done wrong? Or has another solution to this problem?

Thanks.

The newly built page has the same errors. When I remove Bing:

```
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'wrapDateLine': object is null or undefined
```

When I include Bing:

```
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'resources': object is null or undefined
```

I am at the mercy of your expertise.

Comment: Does the page work if you force IE8 mode using the F12 developer tools?

Comment: Actually no. It looks like there is a deeper problem here. I stripped my code all the way to just displaying one Bing base layer map and it still failed. It threw a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resources' of undefined" from the Bing initialization function. I'm going to try building a new project.

Comment: It isn't the browser problem. The code works in XAMPP and fails when I port it over to Visual Studio. I haven't had this problem doing that before. But in XAMPP it works on every browser I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, apparently BING sends its "your key is expired" error message under status 200. OpenLayers, quite reasonably, assumed that status 200 meant "O.K." when BING meant "we're too lazy to do this correctly." Naturally, Chrome Developer Tools, FireBug, and Visual Studio did the same thing and reported no problem and until the script tried to run. So note to the next guy: open the entire response, don't believe the header.